# Site domain not available for community

Tags: community, force.com-sites, custom-domain

I have created a site that is mycompany.force.com that hosts a rather old public knowledge base. Now I want to make a community and the first step is to choose a domain. The problem is that mycompany.force.com is already being used as a site. Is there a way to move the domain to the community or have the community use that domain instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to contact the Salesforce support if you want to use the same domain name for your community, that you already have your site on.

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_sites_migrate_to_community_site.htm&type=5):

> **Can I use the same domain name for my Salesforce Sites and my Communities?**
>
> No, you can’t use the same domain name.
>
> Salesforce Sites and Communities must each use a unique domain name. If you’re using a domain name for your Salesforce site and you want to use it for your communities instead, contact Salesforce Support for assistance with renaming the domain.